# Maven Spring Boot application stuck

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have created a sample Spring Boot application which i can Run with Run as Spring Boot App option in STS. I can also run Junit tests with Run as Junit Option without any issue.

But when i try to package my application with Maven using Run as Maven Build option, application just stuck at some point always.

I have below piece of code at starting level.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String name = scan.next();// It just stuck here especially when i use run as maven build

    Double balance = scan.nextDouble();
    Card card = new Card(name, balance);

    scan.close();
```

My console looks like stuck here

```
    2018-03-11 00:39:58.619  INFO 22835 --- [           main] c.a.o.t.daoImpl.test.JourneyDAOImplTest  : Starting JourneyDAOImplTest on localhost.localdomain with PID 22835 (started by root in /root/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.0.RELEASE/oystercard)
2018-03-11 00:39:58.629  INFO 22835 --- [           main] c.a.o.t.daoImpl.test.JourneyDAOImplTest  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-03-11 00:39:58.931  INFO 22835 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@6c1a5b54: startup date [Sun Mar 11 00:39:58 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-03-11 00:40:04.630  INFO 22835 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@6c1a5b54: startup date [Sun Mar 11 00:39:58 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-03-11 00:40:04.991  INFO 22835 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-03-11 00:40:04.995  INFO 22835 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-03-11 00:40:05.155  INFO 22835 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-03-11 00:40:05.177  INFO 22835 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-03-11 00:40:05.427  INFO 22835 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-03-11 00:40:05.942  INFO 22835 --- [           main] c.a.o.t.daoImpl.test.JourneyDAOImplTest  : Started JourneyDAOImplTest in 8.48 seconds (JVM running for 12.679)
```

I am only expecting two values from `Scan`. where i Have given many values to just show the application stuck at this point.

```
2018-03-11 08:00:50.876  INFO 18520 --- [           main] c.a.o.t.daoImpl.test.JourneyDAOImplTest  : Starting JourneyDAOImplTest on localhost.localdomain with PID 18520 (started by root in /root/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.0.RELEASE/oystercard)
2018-03-11 08:00:50.880  INFO 18520 --- [           main] c.a.o.t.daoImpl.test.JourneyDAOImplTest  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-03-11 08:00:51.105  INFO 18520 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@6c1a5b54: startup date [Sun Mar 11 08:00:51 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-03-11 08:00:59.383  INFO 18520 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@6c1a5b54: startup date [Sun Mar 11 08:00:51 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-03-11 08:00:59.739  INFO 18520 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-03-11 08:00:59.742  INFO 18520 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-03-11 08:00:59.880  INFO 18520 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-03-11 08:00:59.881  INFO 18520 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-03-11 08:01:00.053  INFO 18520 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-03-11 08:01:02.014  INFO 18520 --- [           main] c.a.o.t.daoImpl.test.JourneyDAOImplTest  : Started JourneyDAOImplTest in 12.566 seconds (JVM running for 18.154)

**Rajesh
30.0
30.0
Rajesh
Rajesh
30.0
fdsfdsfdsjfds
46548768672**
```

UPDATE:
When i ran `mvn spring-boot:run`, It works fine.
But If i ran using `mvn clean install spring-boot:run`, it stuck in the middle
Any Help?

Comment: it seems that the application started

Comment: As @NiVeR said the application started just like it should. What were you expecting? Where exactly is the code you showed us located and which class did you start as your main Class?

Comment: The main method simply calls the Run method where i am using scan. You can see the updated code.

Comment: Check for alternative of scan()

Answer (score 1):

The application is stuck because it is waiting for input data in `scan.next()` method call.

As per [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()):

> This method may block while waiting for input to scan, even if a previous invocation of hasNext() returned true.

Comment: Then why the application is running correctly when i choose Run as a "Spring Boot APP" or Run as "JUNIT test". It only stuck when i ran as Maven Build.